# Groovy ( Java ) store time with milliseconds in TransactSQL Database ( Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 )

Tags: t-sql, datetime, grails, groovy, java.util.date

Hello I have a Grails application which uses so far java.util.Date to store a timing value into a Microsoft SQL Server Database.

I load the date values form a .csv file with that format:

```
java.util.Date send_date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").parse(data[1]);
```

If I watch the var `send_date` with my debugger the field for milliseconds has the right value `millis = 241`

The variable `send_date`  which is a `java.util.Date` type creates a `Data Type = datetime` column in my Database but then the value in the Database is `2007-10-04 10:10:53.240` This means the milliseconds are wrong. It always appears random, sometimes it is the right amount of milliseconds sometime +1 or -1.

Does anybody know a other data type which is compatible with my database, I already tried `java.sql.Date` but then I do not have a constructor to add this format `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"` If anybody knows how I can create another date object with this input format please let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server'd DATETIME data type has a 3 ms resolution. If you need a higher resolution use the DATETIME2 data type. It has a 100 ns resolution.